# how to install facebbok plugin for phonegap 3.0.0

Tags: facebook, cordova

I followed phonegap docs and put

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="123**" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="myApp" />
</gap:plugin>
```

in the config.xml file.

i also put a reference to the js files in index.html

```
<script src="js/cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>
<script src="js/facebook-js-sdk.js"></script>
```

but nothing was added after build (local).

what else should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You should follow instructions on https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin